# Is there an option in Visual Studio that sets console background color for each run?

Tags: c#

I know that I can change the console background color with the `Console.BackgroundColor` property. But I want to know if there is an option in Visual Studio that sets the background color to a specific color forever and for each run?
I mean that for every run, the background color for example becomes 'green'.

Comment: You can do that with a single line of code.  It's not a VS option.

Comment: If changing the color of all the consoles suits you, you have the console properties submenu at the top left via the windows system menu: [How To Personalize the Windows Command Prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16815/how-to-personalize-the-windows-command-prompt/). Is that you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[image]

You can find this using:

- Run your console application
- Click the console icon on the top left of your cmd window
- Check "Use Seperate Background"
- Choose the color using RGB

Comment: Hey man. It worked well.
Thank you man.